# What is canvas in HTML 5?

Tags: html, css, canvas, area

What is canvas in HTML 5? I'm a little new as a developer.
Canvas is an HTML area on which you can draw graphics.

```
""500"" id=""mycanvas"" solid="" style=""border:1px" width=""600""></canvas>
```

---

```
var c=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
```

What does it mean?

Comment: @Nisse Engström who are doing -vote.... Mrs. Admin find that who is polling -vote and stop that authority. my reputations are getting down because of that. its really disgusting

Comment: @Vj: I have no idea. Voting data is simply not available to normal users such as you and me. Not even to moderators as far as I know.

Comment: @NisseEngström see i had 8 reputations but now only have 6..and i need 20 reputations to get in to the chat... i really need to get in to chat room because i need to clarify so many things i hate that down voters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**canvas** in HTML 5

The HTML  element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript.

The  element is only a container for graphics. You must use JavaScript to actually draw the graphics.

Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images.

[check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

I'm added an example below,

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: i was really confused about that but now clear.... i have another doubt also..i am a corelDRAW designer also can i convert designs from corelDRAW to HTML? is there any possible?  @dream hunter

Comment: its seems its not advisable to convert from cdr to HTML? @dream hunter

Comment: @VjRagavan please post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) :

> Added in HTML5, the HTML `<canvas>` element can be used to draw graphics via scripting in JavaScript. For example, it can be used to draw graphs, make photo compositions, create animations, or even do real-time video processing or rendering.

Start here : [Canvas tutorial by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)